# Vectorize multiplication in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network

I have the following problem in Tensorflow:

```
#y_true.shape = (8, 256, 512) 
#y_pred.shape = (8, 256, 512, 39) where 39 is the different classes

focal_loss_weight = tf.multiply(y_true, tf.pow(
   tf.subtract(1., y_pred), 0.3))
```

I am trying to find the total loss so I should create a for loop to iterate over 39 classes from y_pred and add them together to a total loss of dimension (8,256,512). How would be the vectorized way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple, assuming I understood correctly:

```
y_true_broadcast = y_true[..., tf.newaxis]  # add axis at the end to make dimensions match
# in this next line, y_true will be replicated over the 39 classes.
# I hope this is what you were asking for...
loss_per_class = y_true_broadcast * tf.pow(1. - y_pred, 0.3)
total_loss = tf.reduce_sum(loss_per_class, axis=-1)  # sum over classes
```

This is fully parallel and should be quite fast.

Comment: It gives me error:
    ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 8 and 256 for 'mul' (op: 'Mul') with input shapes: [8,256,512], [8,256,512,39].

Comment: Thanks for the edit, that happens when you just write down code without testing it... I suppose it works now?